# How to find line number of error in Spoj?

Tags: python

I've been trying to submit a solution in **`Python`** to a problem in Spoj, but I keep getting an `NZEC` runtime error.

Is it possible to find out which line the error is occurring at?

Comment: Run the program on your own computer and look at the error message.

Comment: @GarethRees, I don't get any error message on my computer. I assume the problem is with how the input file on Spoj is.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly:  SPOJ won't tell you - it won't even tell you **which** non-zero exit code you got :-(

The slow way around this is to submit your program many times, changing it each time to exit at a later line.  For example, call `sys.exit()` after your first line.  If you don't get a NZEC complaint, you know your first line wasn't the cause.  Then move `sys.exit()` down a line and try again.  Etc.  It can be a real PITA.

Note:  you can do a form of binary search this way to find the offending line much faster.